# How can I update wth DBFlow in Android?

Tags: android, orm, dbflow, sql-update

I implement te above code, which is the code from the DBFlow tutorial

```
Update<Ant> update = new Update().table(Ant.class).set(Condition.column(Ant$Table.TYPE).eq("other"))
  .where(Condition.column(Ant$Table.TYPE).is("worker"))
  .and(Condition.column(Ant$Table.ISMALE).is(true));
update.queryClose();
```

And the `Update()` and `queryClose()` get colored red.

In fact, In the Update class of DBFlow not even appear the method table() that is shown in the code I've just paste.

Does anybody know how to implement an Update statement? Thank you

Comment: Hi.. i am facing the same issue.. did you find the solution?

Comment: Seems like .table() method has been removed in recent versions of DBFlow, and now the model class is passed in the constructor. @Kayvan's solution should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with `Update()` and `queryClose()`, I solved it by updating the database using an object like this

```js
mObject.setType("other");
mObject.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

The query that you have will return a `Where` Object. Then your `Where` object will have `.queryClose()` method.

```
Where update = new Update().table(Ant.class).set(Condition.column(Ant$Table.TYPE).eq("other"))
  .where(Condition.column(Ant$Table.TYPE).is("worker"))
  .and(Condition.column(Ant$Table.ISMALE).is(true));
update.queryClose();
```

Comment: weird enough, I was having problems and this version of the code seemed to work

Answer (score 0):

U need to upgrade Java Version from 1.6 to 1.7.

in case Android Studio -> open your gradle.build in application folder and fix them

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Documentation is still old, then use it :

```
Where update = new Update<>(Ant.class).set(Condition.column(Ant$Table.TYPE).eq("other"))
  .where(Condition.column(Ant$Table.TYPE).is("worker"))
  .and(Condition.column(Ant$Table.ISMALE).is(true));
update.queryClose();
```